# `git add -A` equivalent for magit

Tags: magit

I'm a very limited git user and most of the time, I just want to stage commit and push my code without too much ceremony.

What's the `git add -A` equivalent for magit? (I want to do it programmatically)

Comment: You might also consider `git commit --all`, you can add `"--all"` to `magit-commit-arguments` so that it's enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>S</kbd> to stage all unstaged changes.

To also include all untracked files (other than .gitignored files), use a prefix argument: <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

You can alternatively type <kbd>s</kbd> on the relevant section headings: "Unstaged changes" and "Untracked files", which you can jump to with <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> respectively.

Comment: is there a way to programmatically do it?

Comment: You can check what elisp functions the respective keyboard shortcuts call and call them directly from a new function.